# Parallel SSH with Custom Parameters to Each Host

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, distributed

There are plenty of threads and documentation about parallel ssh, but I can't find anything on passing custom parameters to each host. Using `pssh` as an example, the hosts file is defined as:

```
111.111.111.111
222.222.222.222
```

However, I want to pass custom parameters to each host via a shell script, like this:

```
111.111.111.111 param1a param1b ...
222.222.222.222 param2a param2b ...
```

Or, better, the hosts and parameters would be split between 2 files.

Because this isn't common, is this misuse of parallel ssh? Should I just create many ssh processes from my script? How should I approach this?

Comment: My current solution is to create ssh processes and background them and wait for them to finish. This works nicely in my case because I can pass the parameters I want, but it makes me have to manage the logs and control them on my own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [GNU parallel](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

Suppose you have a file **argfile**:

```
111.111.111.111 param1a param1b ...
222.222.222.222 param2a param2b ...
```

Then running

```
parallel --colsep ' ' ssh {1} prog {2} {3} ... :::: argfile
```

Would run `prog` on each host with the corresponding parameters. It is important that the number of parameters be the same for each host.

Comment: Great! It's been a while since I've looked at this stuff, but if this works, it looks like the most elegant solution. I didn't mention in my original question that I have an arbitrarily number of servers to pass these parameters to (could be hundreds), and this seems to easily scale. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: If your arguments contain space, then you might want to use TAB (\t) as --colsep (Especially handy if the argfile comes from a spreadsheet).

Comment: If you still want to split the hosts and params into 2 files, then use --xapply, which will read one line from each input source: parallel --xapply ssh {1} prog {2} :::: hosts argfile

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that you can use, after tailoring it to suit your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash
#filename: example.sh
#usage: ./example.sh <par1> <par2> <par3> ... <par6>

#set your ip addresses
$traf1=1.1.1.1
$traf2=2.2.2.2
$traf3=3.3.3.3

#set some custom parameters for your scripts and use them as you wish.
#In this example, I use the first 6 command line parameters passed when run the example.sh


ssh -T $traf1 -l username "/export/home/path/to/script.sh $1  $2" 1>traf1.txt 2>/dev/null &
echo "Fetching data from traffic server 2..."
ssh -T $traf2 -l username "/export/home/path/to/script.sh $3  $4" 1> traf2.txt 2>/dev/null &
echo "Fetching data from traffic server 3..."
ssh -T $traf3 -l username "/export/home/path/to/script.sh $5  $6" 1> traf3.txt 2>/dev/null &

#your application will block on this line, and will only continue if all 
#3 remotely executed scripts will complete
wait
```

Keep in mind that the above requires that you setup [passwordless login](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/152) between the machines, otherwise the solution will break to request for password input.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use Perl:

```
use Net::OpenSSH::Parallel;
use Data::Dumper;

my $pssh = Net::OpenSSH::Parallel->new;

$pssh->add_host('111.111.111.111');
$pssh->add_host('222.222.222.222');

$pssh->push('111.111.111.111', $cmd, $param11, $param12);
$pssh->push('222.222.222.222', $cmd, $param21, $param22);

$pssh->run;

if (my %errors = $ssh->get_errors) {
  print STDERR "ssh errors:\n", Dumper \%errors;
}
```